# Can you please explain this Groovy Script

Tags: groovy, operators

I'm very new to Groovy scripting. I'm trying to understand a script I've came a cross and can someone please explain me what are these steps do? I'm confused about ==~ operator in there. I know ~ is negative, but what does it mean in this context?

```
def matchRegExList = { str, regExList ->
  matched = false
  regExList.each { regEx ->
    if (str ==~ /$regEx/) {
      matched = true
    }
  }
  match_str = matched ? 'matched' : 'did not match'
  INFO("Branch $str $match_str RegEx list $regExList")
  return matched
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a Groovy regular expression operator.

~ Pattern operator

=~ Find operator

==~ Match operator

From these, the Match operator returns a boolean true/false if the argument is a match for the given regular expression.

In your code, there is a closure 'matchRegExList' that takes two arguments. One is the string to be matched, the other is a list of regular expressions. The code matches each regular expression with your string, and if any matches, it will return true, otherwise false.

The code snippet

```
str ==~ /$regEx/
```

is the usage of the Match operator. This will create a pattern from your regex string, match it with your string, and return true or false if there is a match or not.

You can find more info and examples here:
http://www.groovy-lang.org/operators.html#_regular_expression_operators

Comment: Thank you! I found some more basic info on https://www.timroes.de/2015/06/27/groovy-tutorial-for-java-developers/